# Spring Boot - Maven build error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting error while doing maven test for the simple springboot project.
I am able to run Maven validate and compile.

The source code is as below:

```js
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Microservice1Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Microservice1Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

The test code is as below:

```js
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Microservice1ApplicationTests {

 @Test
 public void contextLoads() {
 }

}
```

The error I am getting is as below:

```js
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.895 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: _There are test failures_. So check first which tests fail.  _Please refer to ... target\surefire-reports for the individual test results_

Comment: It is giving error as follows                  Test set: com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.702 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.example.demo.Microservice1ApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Please add this stuff to question and properly formatted not as comment. Edit your question. Try to find the test cases that fail. They either fail for a reason or they are not valid tests.

Comment: Done. can you please have a look. Sorry, I have joined this site today. so not aware of all the formatting options.

Comment: This is the root error, search this site for possible solutions: `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Answer (score 1):

Just read the latest "Caused by":

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
```

So you need somewhere in a configuration xml or yaml something like this:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Where I use the MySQL dialect and I also specify the MySQL Driver (you should check for the proper database in your case).

Finally an Hibernate configuration might look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

There you can see that I add "hibernate.dialect" as a property and the "hibernate.driver" as part of the datasource

Comment: Hi, I had defaulted the Maven repository to .m2/repository and reindexed the maven repository and this fixed the issue. Strange,,,